# Error passing array to a function. It is not able to compile

Tags: java, arrays, variables, non-static

My array should be passed to a function, but my program has an error and does not compile. What am I doing wrong?

> 1. I am getting an error on line 13: "a1e.averData(scores,MAX_SIZE);"
> 2. The error states,"non-static variable scores cannot be referenced from 
>      a static context. Assign Return Value to New Variable"
> 3. I also tried assigning the return value to a new variable.  It looked like this: "float averData = a1e.averData(scores,MAX_SIZE);"
> 4. The error changed to this: "non-static variable scores cannot be referenced from a static context. non-static variable MAX_SIZE cannot be referenced from a static context"
> 5. I have tried moving it from the main to other spots in the program, but it just doesn't seem to want to work for me, and I am unsure of how to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
    package array1example;

    public class Array1example 
    {    
       int i, sum;
       float avg;
       int scores[];
       int MAX_SIZE = 0;
        /**
         *
         * @param args
         */
         public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        /* An example of an array being passed to a function
           This program stores integers in an array
           and computes their average*/


           Array1example a1e = new Array1example(); 
        }

        public Array1example() 
        {
        this.scores = new int[]{5, 5, 12, 17, 11};
        a1e.averData(scores,MAX_SIZE);
        }
        private float averData(int[] scores1, int MAX_SIZE1)
        {

            int size = 0;
            for(i=0, sum=0; i<size; i++) 
            {
            System.out.println("Score " + " = " + scores1[i] );
            sum += (scores1[i]);
        }
            avg = sum / i;
            System.out.println("Average score: " + avg );
        return avg;        
        }

        }
```

Comment: I think you've changed the code and no longer reflects that error and you added more problems by trying to use `a1e` in the constructor. I believe the original issue had to do with trying to pass `scores` inside `main` which wouldn't be allowed directly. You would need to do `a1e.scores/MAX...`

Comment: Geez!  No need to shout!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `a1e.averData(scores,MAX_SIZE);` in your constructor, 
instead change it into `averData(scores,MAX_SIZE);`

Comment: Your Constructor is similar to static context. However your a1e object is non-static.

Comment: This is so because `a1e` is a local variable in your `main` method, so you cannot use it outside that method. Nor do you need to: in your constructor you are inside the object you are contructing, so you can call a method on the object without the dot notation.

Comment: I had tried doing what you had suggested, and it still doesn't compile.

Comment: avg = sum / i;
            System.out.println("Average score: " + avg );
        return avg;

Comment: I have already taken my final, so I no longer need to prepare for the exam.  However, thank you for your time :)